# axis2 service list page is not loading but WSDL is accessible

Tags: apache-axis

I have web services running on Axis2 1.6 within JBoss AS 6.1 as WAR.

Suddenly

http://xxx.xx.xxx.xx:8080/axis2/services/listServices

fails to load in browser.

But,

http://xxx.xx.xxx.xx:8080/axis2/services/MyWebService?wsdl

loads as before.

I have two types of clients to the services.

One Android, the other .NET.

The former works fine, but the latter is not responding.

They all worked until yesterday.

I can't grasp what's going on.

Has anyone had the symptom like this?

Comment: <parameter name="hostname" locked="true">my ip address</parameter>

 I've mistakenly written <my ip address> in axis2.xml while configuring...

 That was the reason.

Answer (score 0):

```
 <parameter name="hostname" locked="true">MY IP ADDRESS</parameter>
```

This can happen when you give wrong ip address at (MY IP ADDRESS).